# Cambiar colores a imagen con css

Tags: css, imagen

me mandaron los siguientes sketch, y los colores de las imagenes cambian cuando se abre el menu.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver ahí las imagenes de las redes sociales y contáctenos es de color fucsia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando se abre el menú los colores cambian a blanco, se que puedo cambiar cargando imagenes diferentes pero me lo piden con estilos, y no se eso como lo hago sin usar photoshop...

Comment: Si te lo piden con css, entonces debes de usar una fuente tipografica, (no imagenes) como fontawesome que traen los iconos que ocupas, y con css cambias el color según vayas necesitando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si son etiquetas  no se le puede cambiar los colores, hay la mejor forma es tener dos tipos de iconos uno de color fucsiay otro blanco y cuando se abre el menu, cambiar de icono por javascript.

ahora si los iconos son clases de alguin blog de tipografia como fontawesome  si puedes cambiar el icono con "Color:#000"

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa es que hagas los iconos en negativo con PNG transparente y les cambies el color del fondo (aunque esto no servirá si cambian el fondo y el color de los iconos)

O usar imágenes svg, que les puedes cambiar el color vía css (pero solo poniéndolas inline, sin referenciar las)

O que las incluyas en el CSS como imágenes base64, si son pocas y/o pequeñas y las pongas como background.

O que uses imágenes PNG normales y emplees  las funciones filter de CSS para cambiarles el color
http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html